# How to get token price with Uniswap v3 GraphQL API

Tags: spring-boot, api, graphql

I am going to get token price with Uniswap v3 GraphQL API from Spring boot.

So I tried to test in Postman with
URL : https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3
and query :

```
{
  factories(first: 5) {
    id
    poolCount
    txCount
    totalVolumeUSD
  }
  bundles(first: 5) {
    id
    ethPriceUSD
  }
}
```

But I couldn't get the result like in thegraph.com.

Please help me with how I can get the token price with Uniswap v3 GraphQL API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postman:

- Ensure the method is POST and not GET
- Ensure the body of the request is raw -> JSON
- Ensure the query is formatted properly `{"query":"{ factories(first: 5) { id poolCount txCount totalVolumeUSD } bundles(first: 5) { id ethPriceUSD }}"}`

[image: Postman Image]

Fire away!

Comment: any idea how to do this for a polygon token using curl?

Comment: I know this is somewhat silly question but Is it real-time? That endpoint seems not spending GRT.

Comment: Almost, there seems to be a slight delay (ms to seconds). Can't speak to the GRT spend.